# How to display 'png' image after clicking on a hyperlink (name of the file) using png?

Tags: php

I have tried code as a result I can able to access the folder image and its filename but unable to display the respective image.

```
$dir = '/var/www/info';
$filearray = array('png');
$dir_info = scandir($dir);
foreach ($dir_info as $file)
{
    $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $filearray) == true)
    {
        echo'<tr><td><a href="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?file=/var/www/info';
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

$name = $_GET['file'];
$mimes = array
(
    'png' => 'image/png'
);
$convert = strtolower(end(explode('.', $name)));
$file = '/var/www/info/'.$name;
header('content-type: '. $mimes[$convert]);
header('content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'";');
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Does the simple `print file_get_contents($file);` work?

Comment: Does the file exist?  Use `file_exists($file);` after declaring `$file` var and the check result to see if file exists

Comment: @MohammadSalehi.....i have checked ..but it is displaying file not exist

Comment: So make sure the file exists in that location (manually check the output of `$file` variable for the file), Also check for the file and directory permission, 644 for file and 755 for directories should be fine.

Comment: The displayed link does not include the filename - `'?file=/var/www/info'` should probably be `'?file=/var/www/info' . $file` ?  If you were clicking that link, it means `$name` would be `/var/www/info` and `$convert` would be `/var/www/info`, none of the following code would work.

Comment: That, and it should not contain the directory path to begin with - or `$file = '/var/www/info/'.$name;` needs to be modified, because right now you would end up with `/var/www/info/var/www/info/some_filename.png`

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Initialize the $filearray variable with the PNG file extension.
$filearray = array('png');

// make sure that $convert variable is a valid PNG extension.
$allowed_extensions = array('png');
if (!in_array($convert, $allowed_extensions)) {
    echo 'Invalid file type';
    exit();
}

// Check file exists
$file = '/var/www/info/' . $_GET['file'];
if (!file_exists($file) || !is_readable($file)) {
    echo 'File does not exist or is not readable';
    exit();
}

// Set the Content-Length header before calling the readfile() function.
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

readfile($file);
```